# HTML5: "ImageData is not defined" error in Firefox for Ubuntu when trying to change prototype

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I'm doing a simple physics simulation (like falling sand) with a <canvas> element which involves per-pixel manipulation; I'm using JavaScript.
I wanted to add a method to the ImageData class that is returned by the getImageData function.

```
ImageData.prototype.isPixel = function(x,y) {
    return (this.data[y*this.width*4 + x*4 +3]!=0); //if alpha for (x,y) is non-zero
}
```

This works perfectly in major browsers on Windows, but in Firefox 4 for Ubuntu an error occurs: "ImageData is not defined"
What am I doing wrong? Or is there just something with the implementation for Ubuntu?

Comment: You cannot always access host objects as global variables. Try something like `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1))` - that will get the actual prototype even if not defined globally.

Comment: thanks @pimvdb then sth like
`var ctx=cvs.getContext("2d"); img=ctx.createImageData(1,1);img.prototype.isPixel=...`would be a solution?

Comment: No, `.prototype` exists on constructors. You want `Object.getPrototypeOf(img).isPixel = ...`, and also `getImageData` instead. I'm not on Ubuntu, though.

Comment: Why are you still using Firefox 4?  Aren't they up to version 16 now?

Comment: Well, in fact it wasn't my computer and for some reason (don't know what reason :P ) I thought it was the newest release (I'm using Chrome normally). It seems though that the version numbers may be quite misleading - Firefox 4 was released in 2011. Version 5 started the "rapid release" phase, with 11 versions in a little bit more than a year... Anyway, `Object.getPrototypeOf` worked - thanks!

Comment: I guess, `ImageData` wasn't yet implemented in version 4. So, it's more about updating the browser.